# Can you relocate to Taiwan after being deported from China?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china, taiwan, deportation, visa-bans

My Ukranian girlfriend was recently deported from China for a minor offense.

She wants to relocate to Taiwan to be closer to me since I'm still in China. The problem is we're worried that might not be possible since China and Taiwan are sort of linked. We're woried she might not be granted access to enter Taiwan.

Can anyone advise whether she will be able to relocate to Taiwan or not?

Comment: Deportation are bad sign, for entering in every country. It shows that she will not follow the rules (and immigration is about rules and bureaucracy). There is only one China [according many countries], but for immigration purposes (and many other things) they are like different states.

Comment: I suppose that since China doesn't even _recognize_ Taiwan, they're not going to share data.

Comment: Sounds like the GF's movement would be longer-term, rather than travel. I think this would be a better fit at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The governments of Taiwan/ROC and mainland China/PRC are completely distinct. That said, if there is a valid, non-political reason for her being deported/getting a criminal record, that will not look favorably on any future immigration applications to any country.